# I'm trying to define a main method, but why is it throwing an error message?

Tags: python, twitter

[image: Below is a picture of my python code.]

```
def main():
  File "<stdin>", line 39
    def main():
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Should I have indented that line just like the other defined methods?

Comment: Please post your code in the question itself as *formatted text*

Comment: Check previous line for extra '('.!!

Comment: Why would you enter all this code at the Python prompt? Write your code in a file.

Comment: Befor define main Please press Enter key tow Show '>>>' then define main code!!

Comment: @DanielRoseman like a text file? I'm very new to Python.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be because of the previous line. Is there any code prior to this definition? Check indentations